# convert xlsx to xlsb

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

Hello I have a code mentioned below. I am trying to refresh the connections and save the file with a different format of excel. So if i just refresh connections and close the file works completely fine for me but if i introduce the Saveas command it fails. So far the below code is what I have which fails to save and .xlsx file to .xlsb

```
FldrM = "C:\XYZ\"
ReportFormat = "D:\template\test.xlsx" 
Mdate = DatePart("M" , Now)
Mdate = Right("0" & Mdate, 2)
DayDate=DatePart("D", Now)
DayDate= Right("0" & DayDate, 2)
Tdate = DatePart("YYYY" , Now) & Right("0" & DatePart("M", Now), 2) & Right("0" & DatePart("D", Now), 2) 
name = Tdate & "_test" & ".xlsx"
filedate = DatePart("YYYY" , Now)& Mdate & DayDate
NewReport = fldrM & name
XlsbReportName = fldrM & name & ".xlsb" 
Logfilename="C:\Log File\test_" & ".txt"
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set myLog = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Logfilename, 8, True)
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")    
Set ofolder = fso.getfolder(FldrM)

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set ObjSource = Objexcel.workbooks.open (NewReport,0,False)

myLog.WriteLine cstr(Now) & ":  " & "in progress"

For Each objConnection In ObjSource.Connections
bBackground = objConnection.OledbConnection.BackgroundQuery
objConnection.OledbConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
objConnection.Refresh
objConnection.OledbConnection.BackgroundQuery = bBackground
   
Next
myLog.WriteLine cstr(Now) & ":  " & "Finished"

j = 1
    
    for j =  1 to objsource.sheets.count
        objsource.sheets(j).visible = true
        SName = objsource.sheets(j).name
        myLog.WriteLine cstr(Now) & ":  Updating Sheet " & SName
        
        If SNAME="sheet1" or SName = "sheet2" 
                objsource.sheets(j).visible = true  
        Else
                objsource.sheets(j).visible = False
            
        end if
    next
    
    myLog.WriteLine cstr(Now) & "all finished updating"     
    objsource.save
    objsource.Saveas Filename:=name & ".xlsb", FileFormat:=51
    myLog.WriteLine cstr(Now) & "saved as required format"  
    objsource.close savechanges=True
    
    objExcel.quit
    set objsource = nothing
    set objExcel = nothing 
    
    myLog.WriteLine cstr(Now) & "bye"   
    myLog.Close
```

this command throws and error and does not save the file as desired :"objsource.Saveas Filename:=name & ".xlsb", FileFormat:=51"

If i remove that specific line from the command then it runs fine opens the excel-> refresh the connections -> and saves it as well as excel and closes it.

But I want to save it to .xlsb

Can someone please assist to that.

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: this extension can not be used with the selected file type. change the file extension in filename @CB_Ron this is what the error is.

Comment: also I tried "objsource.Saveas XlsbReportName" as i tried to declare it in the intial script as well.

Comment: `name` expands to `filename.xlsx`. Is the error identical when using the XlsbReportName variable in `SaveAs`?

Comment: No eventually everything drops down to that specific line. So then error pops out as that 'SaveAs' line and to some specific character. And fails. I cannot attach the screenshot if not I can do that.

Comment: I tried recording a macro and did a saveas with the xlsb format and it spat out `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="...", FileFormat:=xlExcel12` so maybe you need to use `FileFormat:=xlExcel12`? (According to the documentation xlExcel12 = 50)

Comment: This is the exact Error :` This extension can not be used with the selected file type. Change the file extension in the file name text box or select a different file type by changing the save as type.`
Code : `800A03EC`

Comment: I tried with the `FileFormat:=xlExcel12` still that is failing. @garbb

Comment: Creating a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help greatly with debugging this.

Comment: Is this VBA or VBscript? VBScript doesn't support named arguments, so you should get a syntax error there.

Comment: @garbb let me try to do it the way you have explained to create a new and small code and try to see where the breakpoint occurs. Will let you know for sure.

Comment: @GeertBellekens and Lankymart VBScript but I have tried that before and I did not have an error still let me try to break it down to pieces and see how this goes. Thank you all for your help and support.

Comment: @Lankymart can you please not mark this as duplicate and closed as the suggestion provided was partial not fully relevant to what my questions is. Please

Comment: If it's VBScript then remove the vba tag, make a minimal reproducible example and update your question. Chances are you will find the error yourself when doing that.